# Add day of the year as a number between 1-365/366 to file

Tags: text-processing, date

Consider the below extract of a file:

```
19610101   060000  0.4  G
19610101   120000  2.3  G
19610101   180000  ...  .
19610102   150000   
19610102   180000
19610103   060000
........   ......
20150901
```

The leftmost column specifies a date. If one would like to insert a column specifying the day of the year as a number between 1-365/366, how would one go about doing that?

If one were to extract the last four digits of each date, that is 0101,0102, ..., one would have a recursive and increasing sequence of numbers. Where would one go from there? Or is there a simpler implementation?

Comment: That first column is the date in `yyyymmdd` format, right? Does it contain every calendar day in order, or can there be gaps?

Comment: Correct, it is the date in ```yyyymmdd``` and the calendar days are ordered. There could be potential gaps of missing days.

Comment: Linux-based platform (or somewhere else with GNU `date`)?

Comment: Linux-based platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the file `file` with contents

```
19610101   060000  0.4  G
19610101   120000  2.3  G
19610101   180000  ...  .
19610102   150000  ...  .
19610102   180000  ...  .
19610103   060000  ...  .
20150901   ......  ...  .
```

we may use GNU `awk` or `mawk` (both of these have `mktime()` and `strftime()`):

```
awk '
    {
        tspec = sprintf("%4d %.2d %.2d 00 00 00", substr($1,1,4), substr($1,5,2), substr($1,7,2))
        t = mktime(tspec)
        $(NF+1) = strftime("%j",t)
    } { print }' file
```

This creates a Unix timestamp, `t`, from the date parsed from the file's first column (midnight is used as the time).  It then formats the timestamp using `strftime()` with the `%j` format, which will give us the day of the year as a zero-filled integer (see `man strftime`). This number is inserted as the new column, and then the line is printed.

The result:

```
19610101 060000 0.4 G 001
19610101 120000 2.3 G 001
19610101 180000 ... . 001
19610102 150000 ... . 002
19610102 180000 ... . 002
19610103 060000 ... . 003
20150901 ...... ... . 244
```

To get rid of the zero filling, use `$(NF+1) = 0 + strftime(...)`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The file has four columns and doesn't actually include the "Date   Time" line. How would one modify the posted awk command in that regard? What would be the full command to get rid of the zero filling?

Comment: @schn To get rid of the zero filling, just insert `0+` before `strftime`. To not skip the header line remove the `NR>1` (leave the `{` though). The code will always insert a new column, so if you have four columns, you'll get a new fifth one.

Comment: @schn Also, when giving sample data in a question that requires parsing and modifying that data, do consider posting data that is actually representative of the real data.

Comment: @Kusalananda The question has been edited to include what is actually in the file. The code gives mixed results. It produces another column with the number of the day (with the zero filling removed), but sometimes these are out of sync. It also seems to loop through the file several times, with different outputs. See attached output.

Comment: ```19740519 120000 22.8 G 129```                                                                          ```19740519 180000 17.4 G 129```                                                                       ```19740520 060000 11.5 G 120``` and

Comment: The looping of the file has been resolved. The numbering of days seem to go astray at times, jumping from 213 one day to 244 the next day. As edited in the question, there are days where the time entries are two or three, and at different hours (120000 and 180000 one day, 150000 the next day). Does this affect the execution of the code?

Comment: This also has been resolved by changing the third ```substr``` to ```substr($1,7,2)```.

Comment: @Kusalananda A bonus question: the file's original format is ```1961-01-01;06:00:00;0.4;G;``` and there is undesired data preceding it. Using the command ```awk -F ';' 'x==1 {print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4} /undesired_data/ {x=1}' ``` followed by a ```sed``` command to remove the ```-``` and ```:```, the desired data is extracted. Is it possible to combine the awk command into a single one, separating the columns as well as generating the count of days as above? As two separate awk commands it seems to loop over the file generating erraneous output.

Comment: @schn Of course you can. It's just a matter of using the right offsets in the three calls to the `substr()` command. Right now I'm using 1, 5 and 7. Taking the dashes into account would probably mean having to use 1, 6 and 9. Be sure you use `-F ';'` and also `-v OFS=';'` (for the output field delimiter).

Comment: How would the beginning of the command look like? ```awk -F ';' -v 'OFS=;' '{x==1} ...```would throw an error.

Comment: @schn That looks correct, but `{x==1}` makes no sense (and it's different from what you had in your earlier comment).

Comment: Right, it's supposed to be ```x==1```. Currently the following is producing an output without the timestamp code taking effect ```awk -F';' -v OFS=';'
 '{
        tspec = sprintf("%4d %.2d %.2d 00 00 00", substr($1,1,4), substr($1,6,7), substr($1,9,10))
        t = mktime(tspec)
        $(NF+1) = 0 + strftime("%j",t)
    } x==1 {print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4} /undesired_data/ {x=1}' ```

Comment: Since the unformatted file doesn't start with the year/time/... line, maybe the timestamp code doesn't take effect on that line.

Comment: @schn If you're using that on one line, then each `awk` statement has to be separated from the next with `;`. If you want to print all fields, just use `print` (no need to specify each individual field; you're leaving the new 5th field out). This would use `OFS` as the field separator (you set this to `;`, but space is the default).  I will not answer more followup question in this comment thread. If you have further questions about this, or about how `awk` works, then consider asking a new separate question on the site about this.

Comment: Okay. Appreciate the feedback. A new, separate question has been asked where the full commands are specified (https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/550282/380342).

Answer (score 0):

If your data are homogeneous, ex.

```
$ cat file
Date       Time
19610101   060000
19610101   120000
19610101   060000
19610102   120000
19610102   060000
19610102   120000
20150901   060000
```

then Miller (`mlr`) might be a good choice:

```
$ mlr --pprint --fs " " --repifs put -S '
    $Day = strftime(strptime($Date,"%Y%m%d"),"%j")
' file
Date     Time   Day
19610101 060000 001
19610101 120000 001
19610101 060000 001
19610102 120000 002
19610102 060000 002
19610102 120000 002
20150901 060000 244
```

Note the use of `-S` to coerce the undelimited `YYYYmmmdd` field into string type for `strptime` (by default, it is parsed as an integer).