# Including timestamp into awk command

Tags: text-processing, awk

Consider a bunch of almost identical csv files. They all have in common the part shown, i.e. a line with `Date;Time;...` followed by four columns of data (some of the first lines have six columns, where the fifth column is empty and the sixth is mere descriptive text). There is also descriptive text separated into various columns preceding the line `Date;Time;...`

```
...
...
Date;Time;Airtemp;Quality;;Other info
1961-01-01;06:00:00;0.4;G;;...
1961-01-01;12:00:00;2.3;G;;...
1961-01-01;18:00:00;...;.;;...
1961-01-02;15:00:00;...;.  
..........;........;...;.
2015-09-01;........;...;.
```

Using the following commands (*)

```
awk -F ';' 'x==1 {print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4} /Date/ {x=1}' file >> new_file

sed -i '' 's/[-:,]//g' new_file
```

creates a `new_file` with the following format

```
19610101   060000  0.4  G 
19610101   120000  2.3  G 
19610101   180000  ...  . 
19610102   150000  ...  .        
19610102   180000  ...  .       
19610103   060000  ...  .      
........   ......  ...  .
20150901   ......  ...  .
```

Now, using the command (**)

```
awk '
     {
        tspec = sprintf("%4d %.2d %.2d 00 00 00", substr($1,1,4), substr($2,1,2), substr($2,3,4))
        t = mktime(tspec)
        $(NF+1) = 0 + strftime("%j",t)
    } {print}' new_file
```

creates another column in `new_file` with a numbering of days.

```
19610101   060000  0.4  G 1
19610101   120000  2.3  G 1
19610101   180000  ...  . 1
19610102   150000  ...  . 2
19610102   180000  ...  . 2
19610103   060000  ...  . 3
........   ......  ...  . .
20150901   ......  ...  . .
```

Is there a way to combine commands (*) and (**) in one script? Currently these are run in two separate ones.

Comment: Is the day counting to be consecutive just how many days, or days since day 1? (i.e. if days are missing data, are they to be skipped in the numbering or not?)

Comment: @Fiximan The day counting is consecutive until the date hits a new year. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/550197/380342

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining the two `awk` commands (and the `sed`):

```
awk -F ';' '
    x == 1 {
        gsub("[:,-]", "")
        tspec = sprintf("%4d %.2d %.2d 00 00 00", substr($1,1,4), substr($1,5,2), substr($1,7,4))
        t = mktime(tspec)
        print $1, $2, $3, $4, 0 + strftime("%j", t)
    }
    /Date/ { x = 1 }' file
```

This assumes that you are using either GNU `awk` or `mawk` (not BSD `awk`, which may not implement `mktime()` or `strftime()`).

The code combines the two `awk` commands and the `sed` (using `gsub()`), and I've also taken the liberty to correct the parsing of the date for setting `tspec`.

Given a file,

```
...
...
Date;Time;Airtemp;Quality;;Other info
1961-01-01;06:00:00;0.4;G;;...
1961-01-01;12:00:00;2.3;G;;...
1961-01-01;18:00:00;...;.;;...
1961-01-02;15:00:00;...;.
2015-09-01;........;...;.
```

this would produce

```
19610101 060000 0.4 G 1
19610101 120000 2.3 G 1
19610101 180000 ... . 1
19610102 150000 ... . 2
20150901 ........ ... . 244
```

Note that space is the default output field separator (`OFS`), so if you are not setting `OFS` to anything explicitly you don't (shouldn't) have to output the spaces using `" "` between each output field.

Comment: Probably one final tweak. If one were to replace ```gsub("-","",$1)``` with ```gsub("-"," ",$1)``` so that the date formats to ```1961 01 01```, how could one remove the leading zeros from the month and day? Would ```gensub```be an option, and if so, how would one specify the "how" argument?

Comment: @schn By changing the second parameter in the last two `substr()` calls so that they look at the correct offset in the string. The second needs to be `substr($1,6,2)` (to pick up two characters one step further along the string) and the last one `substr($1,9,2)` (to pick up two characters two steps further along the string).  I've never ever had to use `gensub` for anything.

Comment: This would preserve the correct day count, but would it remove the leading 0s in the months and days? That is, the leading zeros in ```01``` and  ```01```in ```1961 01 01```.

Comment: @schn Did you try it? The answer is that it would preserve the leading zeroes. The whole date, `1961 01 01` is a single string, and it's just copied without further modifications.

Comment: Right. The output of the first line is ```1961 01 01 060000 0.4 G 1```. Now would there be a way to remove the leading zeros of ```01``` and ```01``` to get ```1961 1 1 060000 0.4 G 1``` instead?

Comment: @schn With my original code in the answer, change `gsub(...)` to `gsub("-", " ", $1)` and then, after assigning to `tspec`, insert _another_ `gsub(" 0?", " ", $1)`. That way we don't have to keep track of whether the days are zero filled or not when creating `tspec` (`mktime()` requires zero filled day and month).

Comment: @schn Again, I won't be answering further follow-up questions. This is not really a discussion forum.

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to answer since you're not showing us real data. But, if I understand you correctly, you don't need to consider the timestamp at all. based on your desired output, you just want to remove the `-` and `:` from the input and add the extra column:

```
$ awk -F';' '{day=substr($1,9,2); gsub(/[:-]/,""); printf "%s;%.1d\n",$0,day}' file
19610101;060000;0.4;G;...;1
19610101;120000;2.3;G;...;1
19610101;180000;...;.;1
19610102;150000;...;.  ;2
..........;........;...;.;0
20150901;........;...;.;1
```

Or, if you want tab-separated columns as you show (I think) in your desired output:

```
 $ awk -F';' -vOFS="\t" '{day=substr($1,9,2); gsub(/[:-]/,""); print $1,$2,$3,$4, sprintf("%.1d",day)}' file
19610101    060000  0.4 G   1
19610101    120000  2.3 G   1
19610101    180000  ... .   1
19610102    150000  ... .   2
..........  ........    ... .   0
20150901    ........    ... .   1
```

Comment: The question has been edited.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing $4 to $5 to show the day of year

`{print $1 " " $2 " " $3 " " $4}`